# Is it wrong to use functions like CGRectMake in a method rather than creating a variable first?

Tags: objective-c

for example:

```
someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 205, 200, 200)];
```

rather than:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(120, 205, 200, 200);
someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

I seems like I only see the second example. Is it just for readability? Or is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of style. The two are equivalent and will probably compile to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Only difference is as you already pointed out, readability. It also makes the CGRect structure reusable other places in your code if you need the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Both pieces of code have identical effect. There could be a couple of reasons for using the second pattern:

- The code can be easier to read. You can name the variable to be more descriptive.
- If you're reusing the same rect many times, it might make sense to declare it once and reuse it. While CGRectMake is an inexpensive operation, it could still be a good practice, especially if you're running this code many times in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the second option, is if you make a lot of `CGRect`s in the same scope, you'll need to either prevent your code from redefining `frame`, overwrite the variable, or come up with different names for different frames.

To make your code more portable, I would go with the first option every time.  But if it got a little too complex, then I'd split it out for readability's sake.